# Load Runner : Failed to Create OTA Integration object

Tags: load, automated-tests, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have installed Load Runner 11 successfully in my machine. But when I open the VU Generator, it throws a pop up which says "Failed to create OTA integration object". And then simultaneously, it throws another alert which says "Failed to create FileDialog Object".

When I try to create a new virtual user, the VU generator gets closed automatically.

Please suggest any way out if anybody has encountered similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply repairing the installation process, there were some dll files which were not registered in the installation at the first place.

With Best Regards
SK